# Pgfplots not working with Pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am writing a document using LaTeX which must contain both graphs and tables. For the graphs I have been using `pgfplots` and this has worked brilliantly. Now I needed to insert a few tables and was trying to do so using `pgfplotstable`, however, the moment I add `\usepackage{pgfplotstable}` to the document I am getting the following error:

> "! Package pgfplots Error: This style is supposed to be constant.."

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error and what I can do to fix it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{color} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} } 
\usepackage{Pgfplots} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\bibliography{Biblog.bib} 
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you post your full preamble? Something is renaming the line legend I think.

Comment: you mean this:
`\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{Pgfplots}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\bibliography{Biblog.bib}

\begin{document}`

Comment: Yes. Thanks. You need to write `\usepackage{pgfplots}` without the capitalized `P`

Comment: Seems Like that was the whole problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As percusse said in the comment above, The issue was that I had `\usepackage{Pgfplots}` rather then `\usepackage{pgfplots}`.